# What color grapes are "Malaga grapes"?

Tags: substitutions, grapes

I've got an old (~1920's) fruit salad recipe that calls for Malaga grapes. My grocery store has "white" and "red" (and occasionally "black") -- which would be the appropriate substitute? Or is this not referring to a color, but rather a region that grows a lot of particularly nice grapes? (I'm finding *lots* of Google hits for Malaga wines...)

Comment: The famous wines from the Malaga area tend to be dessert type wines made from white grapes so my guess would be sweet white grapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also googled it and it seems that sweet white or green grapes are, indeed, probably the closest answer. Since it is a fruit salad, you may want to choose whichever of the grapes is sweetest rather than choosing by color.

[Winemonger's page on malaga](http://winemonger.com/catalog/grapes_info.php?grape_name_id=147) says that it is a white wine grape and can be called by the following names:

- Hunter Riesling (Australia)
- Blanc Doux / Chevrier / [Semillon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9millon) (France)
- Boal / Wyndruif (South Africa)
- Green Grape (United Kingdom)
- [Semillon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9millon) (United States)

The wikipedia link for Sémillon describes that as a sweet, golden grape.

This [interesting Chicago Tribune article](http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1890/11/04/page/9/article/what-we-call-malaga-grapes) from 1890 about what people in NY fruit markets were calling Malaga grapes also indicates that it is a "white or pinkish white" grape, and not the true Malaga grapes, which that article claims were too delicate to ship.

Comment: Thank you -- I think I agree that flavor over color is the best way forward! :)